# Azure VM CentOS 7.3 to support H.323 and SIP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, h.323

I was told Azure VM as video server can't support H.323 and SIP because the IP address is NATed. The NAT is required to have ALG (Application Layer Gateway function) to support H.323 and SIP NAT.

Or VM needs to direct obtain public IP address instead of through Azure to perform NAT. The same problem is also in AWS cloud.

I searched azure document and contacted azure support to verify but so far I do not have answer.

to setup system and testing is one of options but meant I need to involve application team to install system.

also, I was told Azure VM can direct get public IP address instead of NAT. Is it true?  Can anyone share document link or powershell with me for study?

Has anyone implement H.323 and SIP server in azure?  Can share how you configure in azure?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I used H.323 on both Azure and AWS. Due to the NATing you need a software that is able to translate between the public IP and the private IPs, like the free [GNU Gatekeeper](https://www.gnugk.org).

Azure limits the number of ports you can open to 150, so you should always use RTP multiplexing so you don't hit that limit. AWS doesn't have that problem and is better supported by the GNU Gatekeeper, but everything also works on Azure.

Comment: Is it possible to use exiting Azure market commercial image to solve H.323 issue instead of to setup GNU Gatekeeper? I saw Cisco CSR and Fotigate are also available. And is not GNU Gatekeeper VM NATed as well? Please advise and thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of a market place image that does H.323. The GNU Gatekeeper VM is NATed of course but has proxy code to translate the IPs.